# c# Custom Control Listview over panel

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, custom-controls, panel

I have a custom control in winform, which is a search textbox. It has a listview under it and whenever the user starts to type on the textbox listview is populated with the possible matches. 
Listviews height is change according to the number of items in listview.

The custom control is placed into a form , where there is a panel in the middle. 
Whenever the listview expands , the part of listview that should go over panel is going behind, where user is unable to read the items , because panel is blocking it.

Is there a way to make listview to go over the panel ?
thanks

Comment: Try this method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront.aspx. You can also try to use the Document Outline tool window to change the controls order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
panel.SendToBack();
```

or

```
customControl.BringToFront();
```